# How to solve an integral with general polynomials in denominator?: $\int_0^z \frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}\ dx ,$

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

In solving a problem at some point I have obtained the following integral:

$$\int_0^z \frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}\ dx ,$$

where q is any positive integer such that $1<q<\infty$, and z is an arbitrary, general constant.

I have tried simplifying it through integration by parts, but still I obtain a similar integral. I also tried various variable changes, but none have worked so far. I am back to square one and don't know how to proceed really. Mathematica won't be of any help :)

Comment: You can expand the numerators and expand the integral into 4 simpler ones.

Comment: Yes, but then still there is a (q+2) degree polynomial in the denominator of each one of the integrals

Comment: [Partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)?

Comment: Multiply and divide the numerator by $x$ and split it using partial fractions as suggested by @metamorphy to yield two simple integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the integrand can be fractionalized as

$$\frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}
= \frac{q}{1-x}+ \sum_{k=1}^{q}\frac1{x-x_k}
$$
where $ x_k = e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{q+1}}$ is the $k$-th unit root of $1-x^{q+1}=0$. Then, integrate to obtain

$$ \int_0^z \frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}\ dx 
= -q\ln(1-z)
+ \sum_{k=1}^{q}\ln\frac{x_k-z}{x_k}$$

Comment: (+1) How do you fractionalize? Note that your partial sum had a [“more closed” form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+ln%28%28e%5E%282+pi+i%29%2F%28q%2B1%29%29-z%29%29+from+k%3D1+to+q).

Comment: @TymaGaidash - Let 
$$\frac{1-x^q}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}
= \sum_{k=0}^{q}\frac{c_k}{x-x_k}
$$
Then, find $c_k$ with the L’hopital limit rule. You’re right. The resulting sum would reduce to a compact form.

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1-x^q}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)} =\frac{1}{x \left(x^{q+1}-1\right)}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x \left(x^{q+1}-1\right)}=\frac{\log \left(1-x^{q+1}\right)}{q+1}-\log (x)$$
$$\int \frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}\,dx=\log \left(1-x^{q+1}\right)-(q+1)\log(1-x)$$
$$\int_0^z \frac{(q+1)(1-x^q)}{(1-x^{q+1})(1-x)}\,dx=\log \left(1-z^{q+1}\right)-(q+1)\log(1-z)$$